# What's the meaning of 'the underdog' in 'This outfit would be the underdog to a stiff breeze'

Tags: meaning

I have seen the sentence 'This outfit would be the underdog to a stiff breeze.' in a quote of the newspaper 'TIMES'.

I was looking for 'breeze' in the collins online dictionary and this phrase appears as an example, but without context.

If you look 'underdog' in the dictionary, you get: 'The underdog in a competition or situation is the person who seems least likely to succeed or win'. But I don't know how to apply this definition to the clothes. I can't understand what's the meaning of 'the underdog' in the sentence.

Comment: What does the dictionary entry for *underdog* suggest? And what is the larger context for the quote?

Comment: I was looking for 'breeze' in the collins online dictionary and this phrase appears as an example, but without context.

I have edited my question to be make it more explanatory.

Comment: It's also given as an example in the Collins Dictionary entry for [**stiff**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stiff).

Comment: Erm...without the rest of the context from the Times article...we don't really know that "outfit" refers to clothes. It has other usages...such as _team_, or _group_.

Comment: There is a fraction of the article about golf in *The Times* shown [here](https://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/us-ryder-cup-team-rivals-only-liechtenstein-navy-for-intimidation-power-3x59pqplqcm) but from the tone of what's accessible, I would take it all with a pinch of salt. It is also in clear in [this blog](https://blog.kir.com/?p=3349). *"This outfit would be the underdog to a stiff breeze. Or do Brett Wetterich, Zach Johnson, J.J. Henry and Vaughn Taylor make your timbers shiver? It sounds like somebody’s Webelos troop. None of those four have ever played in a Ryder Cup before."*

Comment: Here's an extensive quote from what appears to be the original Sports Illustrated article: http://geoffdshackelford.squarespace.com/homepage/2006/8/22/reilly-the-single-worst-squad-weve-ever-taken-to-a-ryder-cup.html

Comment: So, "a puff of wind would put them off their game..."

Comment: That's a strained metaphor, to think of a dress and the wind in a competition.

Comment: https://youtu.be/tEVsRLhet2k

Comment: Why are you assuming that *outfit* means *clothing*? When I heard the sentence, I immediately thought that it meant *organization*. (And *underdog* is being used figuratively—or at least descriptively—in just the way it's defined.) In short, there is no way of ***really*** knowing the meaning of the sentence without more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is extended context from [Geoff Shackleford](http://geoffdshackelford.squarespace.com/homepage/2006/8/22/reilly-the-single-worst-squad-weve-ever-taken-to-a-ryder-cup.html), quoting Sports Illustrated contributor Rick Reilly:

> **This outfit would be the underdog to a stiff breeze**. Or do Brett Wetterich, Zach Johnson, J.J. Henry and Vaughn Taylor make your timbers shiver? It sounds like somebody's Webelos troop. None of those four have ever played in a Ryder Cup before. Three of them missed the cut at last week's PGA, and Henry finished 41st.

An **underdog** is one who is not favored to win in a contest - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/underdog) calls them a "predicted loser." The [Ryder Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryder_Cup) is in golf. So the writer is saying - rather colorfully -  that a stiff breeze (a wind that is a bit more than mild) would outcompete these professional golfers. It's an exaggeration, like a pro soccer team being underdogs to an age-10 team.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue in this particular case, seems to be that *outfit* doesn't mean *clothes*, but rather the second definition:

> a group of people undertaking a particular activity together, as a
>   group of musicians, a military unit, or a business concern.

Combined with TaliesinMerlin's answer above, that should resolve your confusion.